# django pagination "That page contains no results"

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-pagination

I want to use django pagination. The first page is able to load products but the last page is not showing them.

Here is my index view:

```
def index(request):

    categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_category=None)

    product_list = Product.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).order_by('created_at')
    paginator = Paginator(product_list, 1) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get("page",1)

    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        products = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        products = paginator.page(1)

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'categories': categories
    }
    return render(request, 'product/urunler.html', context)
```

Here is my template:

```
<div class="blog-pagination">
    <ul class="flat-pagination style1">
        {% if products.has_previous %}
            <li class="prev">
                <a href="?page={{products.previous_page_number}}" title="">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/icons/left-1.png' %}" alt="">Önceki Sayfa
                </a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="prev">
                <a href="#" title="">
                    <img src="{% static 'images/icons/left-1.png' %}" alt="">Önceki Sayfa
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in products.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if products.number == i %}
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="?page={{i}}" class="waves-effect" title="">{{i}}</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li>
                    <a href="?page={{i}}" class="waves-effect" title="">{{i}}</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if products.has_previous %}
            <li class="next">
                <a href="?page={{products.next_page_number}}" title="">
                    Sonraki Sayfa
                    <img src="{% static 'images/icons/right-1.png' %}" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
        {% if products.has_next %}
            <li class="next">
                    <a href="" title="">
                        Sonraki Sayfa
                        <img src="{% static 'images/icons/right-1.png' %}" alt="">
                    </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}                                                           
        {% endif %}                           
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I have 2 products in my database I'm able to show the first page but the last page is not showing here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
ecommerce_1            |     response = get_response(request)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
ecommerce_1            |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
ecommerce_1            |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/ecommerce/Product/views.py", line 22, in index
ecommerce_1            |     return render(request, 'product/urunler.html', context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
ecommerce_1            |     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
ecommerce_1            |     return template.render(context, request)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
ecommerce_1            |     return self.template.render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
ecommerce_1            |     return self._render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
ecommerce_1            |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
ecommerce_1            |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
ecommerce_1            |     return self.render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
ecommerce_1            |     return compiled_parent._render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
ecommerce_1            |     return self.nodelist.render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
ecommerce_1            |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
ecommerce_1            |     return self.render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
ecommerce_1            |     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
ecommerce_1            |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
ecommerce_1            |     return self.render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 322, in render
ecommerce_1            |     return nodelist.render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
ecommerce_1            |     bit = node.render_annotated(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
ecommerce_1            |     return self.render(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1040, in render
ecommerce_1            |     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 708, in resolve
ecommerce_1            |     obj = self.var.resolve(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 849, in resolve
ecommerce_1            |     value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 911, in _resolve_lookup
ecommerce_1            |     current = current()
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 158, in next_page_number
ecommerce_1            |     return self.paginator.validate_number(self.number + 1)
ecommerce_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 50, in validate_number
ecommerce_1            |     raise EmptyPage(_('That page contains no results'))
```

There is no error in the first page but the last page always comes with errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking `has_previous` but then including `next_page_number`. It looks like you want to include `previous_page_number` instead:

```
{% if products.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page={{products.previous_page_number}}" title="">Previous</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code after for loop you are checking for has_previous and also you are making minor mistakes. your code after for loop should be

```
{% if products.has_next %}
 <li class="next">
  <a href="?page={{products.next_page_number}}" title="">Sonraki Sayfa
    <img src="{% static 'images/icons/right-1.png' %}" alt=""></a>
 </li>
{% else %}
 <li class="next">
  <a href="" title="">Sonraki Sayfa
    <img src="{% static 'images/icons/right-1.png' %}" alt=""></a>
 </li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is it also possible that you are making some tryes with paginators and you inserted more than one in you template to test their work/style?
If is that so, the django tags still work even if you comment the lines out.
So, if you want to test your paginator, you are forced to remove the others completely.